# Scala distributed execution of function objects

Tags: scala, akka, rpc, apache-spark, finagle

Given the following function objects,

```
val f : Int => Double = (i:Int) => i + 0.1

val g1 : Double => Double = (x:Double) => x*10

val g2 : Double => Double = (x:Double) => x/10

val h : (Double,Double) => Double = (x:Double,y:Double) => x+y
```

and for instance 3 remote servers or nodes (IP xxx.xxx.xxx.1, IP 2 and IP 3), how to distribute the execution of this program,

```
val fx = f(1)
val g1x = g1( fx )
val g2x = g2( fx )
val res = h ( g1x, g2x )
```

so that

- `fx` is computed in IP 1,
- `g1x` is computed in IP 2,
- `g2x` is computed in IP 3,
- `res` is computed in IP 1

May Scala Akka or Apache Spark provide a simple approach to this ?

**Update**

- RPC (Remote Procedure Call) [Finagle](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/) as suggested by @pkinsky may be a feasible choice.
- Consider load-balancing policies as a mechanism for selecting a node for execution, at least *any free available* node policy.

Comment: question, why are you using function vals instead of defs?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee no special reason, the question may well be stated for methods, truly a choice if it leads to a good solution :)

Comment: Do you want to serialize your functions, send them to remote servers, have the remote servers execute them, serialize the results, and return them to you? Or do you just need an RPC library? If it's the second, check out twitter's open-source Finagle library.

Comment: @pkinsky many thanks for the ideas, novel in this, unsure which are the qualities of each option...

Comment: @pkinsky after quick check at RPC Finagle, it looks very promising...

Comment: one of the great things about writing functional type operations (map, fold, reduce) on collections in languages like scala is that you can write the logic and then with sometimes almost no work put any backend behind it (serial, parallel collections, apache-spark). So my recommendation is to write your code like that and then evaluate the results of using various backends

Comment: @enzyme you almost certainly want the second option. Check out twitter's intro to the topic & step-by-step distributed search engine project.
http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html
http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/searchbird.html

Comment: @enzyme What mechanism should determine where the computation takes place?

Comment: @EECOLOR (any) load-balancing policy, at least "free available node" policy.

Comment: @enzyme If you have all the functions present at all of the nodes you could use Akka where the message contains the name of the method and the parameters. If you want to send functions, you might look into the Spores project which aims (in combination with Pickles) to safely serialize functions to be executed elsewhere.

Comment: @EECOLOR many thanks, looking forward to a draft/example on this, looks highly promising :) how to pass a message with function name and (variable number) of arguments ?

Comment: @enzyme I probably used the wrong words. You can have `Method1(arg1, arg2)` and `Method2(arg1)` as messages. Then in your `receive` method you execute the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can speak for **Apache Spark**. It can do what you are looking for with the code below. But it's not designed for this kind of parallel computation. It is designed for parallel computation where you also have a large amount of parallel *data* distributed on many machines. So the solution looks a bit silly, as we distribute a single integer across a single machine for example (for `f(1)`).

Also, Spark is designed to run the same computation on all the data. So running `g1()` and `g2()` in parallel goes a bit against the design. (It's possible, but not elegant, as you see.)

```
// Distribute the input (1) across 1 machine.
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1), numSlices = 1)
// Run f() on the input, collect the results and take the first (and only) result.
val fx = rdd1.map(f(_)).collect.head
// The next stage's input will be (1, fx), (2, fx) distributed across 2 machines.
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, fx), (2, fx)), numSlices = 2)
// Run g1() on one machine, g2() on the other.
val gxs = rdd2.map {
  case (1, x) => g1(x)
  case (2, x) => g2(x)
}.collect
val g1x = gxs(0)
val g2x = gxs(1)
// Same deal for h() as for f(). The input is (g1x, g2x), distributed to 1 machine.
val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq((g1x, g2x)), numSlices = 1)
val res = rdd3.map { case (g1x, g2x) => h(g1x, g2x) }.collect.head
```

You can see that Spark code is based around the concept of **RDDs**. An RDD is like an array, except it's partitioned across multiple machines. `sc.parallelize()` creates such a parallel collection from a local collection. For example `rdd2` in the above code will be created from the local collection `Seq((1, fx), (2, fx))` and split across two machines. One machine will have `Seq((1, fx))`, the other will have `Seq((2, fx))`.

Next we do a **transformation** on the RDD. `map` is a common transformation that creates a new RDD of the same length by applying a function to each element. (Same as Scala's `map`.) The `map` we run on `rdd2` will replace `(1, x)` with `g1(x)` and `(2, x)` with `g2(x)`. So on one machine it will cause `g1()` to run, while on the other `g2()` will run.

Transformations run lazily, only when you want to access the results. The methods that access the results are called **actions**. The most straightforward example is `collect`, which downloads the contents of the entire RDD from the cluster to the local machine. (It is exactly the opposite of `sc.parallelize()`.)

You can try and see all this if you download Spark, start `bin/spark-shell`, and copy your function definitions and the above code into the shell.

Comment: Thanks a heap, can you detail a bit further on `Seq((1, fx), (2, fx)` and subsequent `map` ?

Comment: I've added a few paragraphs to explain. Let me know if you still have questions!